# ATM FSM has unknown output

Tags: verilog

in my assignment, I was asked a question to design an ATM machine using state diagram in verilog HDL . I designed in this way but it is not showing correct output actually any output is not being shown . Can anyone please check? State diagram used for this is attached in the image.

Design a virtual/digital ATM machine using the Mealy model with the following features:

(i) Flashes a green light when cash is available and the machine is ready

(ii) Flashes a red light when cash is not available or there is a machine defect

(iii) When a card is inserted, it asks for a pin if the card is legal or undamaged, else returns a
message asking for resubmission.

(iv) If the wrong pin is entered, asks for re-entry of the pin at the first instant, when the second
entry is also wrong, takes the card in, raises an alarm, and goes back to the rest state.

(v) If the pin is right, prompts for an amount to be dispensed.

(vi) If the amount is more than in store, gives a sign of not enough cash and goes to rest state.

(vii) If the amount is less than in store, dispense the amount and get back to the rest state.

[image]

```
module Mealy_atm (output reg
                  green,red,askpin,carddam,insuf,alarm,askamt,wrongpin,collect,input cash,legal, clock, reset,input
                  [2:0]epin,amt,prepin,arepin,bal); //module for atm 
   reg [2: 0] state, next_state; //reg variables for states 
   wire       pin,wpin,equ,les; //wire variables required 
   parameter S0 = 3'b000, S1 = 3'b001, S2 = 3'b010, S3 = 3'b011,S4 =3'b100; //required parameters 
   comparator M1 (pin,wpin,epin,prepin); //instantiation of comparator 
   comparator M2 (equ,les,amt,bal); //instantiation of comparator for amount 
   assign amtok=equ||les; //assigning value of amtok 
   comparator M3 (repin,wpin,arepin,prepin); //instantiation of comparator for repin 
   always @ ( posedge clock, negedge reset) //always block for block 
     begin //begin of always block 
        if (reset == 0) state <= S0; //reset of states 
        else state <= next_state; //assigning next state 
     end //end of always block 
   always @ (state,cash,legal,pin,amtok,repin) //always for nextstate caluculation 
     begin //begin for always block  
        case (state) //case for assigning next state depending on next state 
          S0: if (cash) next_state <= S1; else next_state <= S0; //next state if cash is present in atm 
          S1: if (legal) next_state <= S2; else next_state <= S1; //next state if card is legal 
          S2: if (pin) next_state <= S3; else next_state <= S4; //next state if pin is correct 
          S3: if (amtok) next_state <= S1; else next_state <= S1; //next state if amount is less than balance 
          //in atm 
          S4: if (repin) next_state<= S3; else next_state <= S1; //next state re-entered pin is correct 
        endcase //end of case 
     end //end of always block 
   always @ (state) //always block for outputs 
     begin //begin for always block 
        case (state) //case for different outputs in different in states 
          S0: begin //begin for outputs for S0 state 
             carddam <=1'b0; //outputs for S0 state 
             insuf<=1'b0; //outputs for S0 state 
             collect <=1'b0; //outputs for S0 state 
             alarm<=1'b0; //outputs for S0 state 
             askamt<=1'b0; //outputs for S0 state 
             askpin<=1'b0; //outputs for S0 state 
             wrongpin<=1'b0; //outputs for S0 state 
             green<=1'b0; //outputs for S0 state 
             if(!cash) red <=1'b1; //outputs for S0 state 
          end //end for outputs for S0 state 
          S1: begin //begin for outputs for S1 state 
             red <=1'b0; //outputs for S1 state 
             insuf<=1'b0; //outputs for S1 state 
             collect <=1'b0; //outputs for S1 state 
             alarm<=1'b0; //outputs for S1 state 
             askamt<=1'b0; //outputs for S1 state 
             askpin<=1'b0; //outputs for S1 state 
             wrongpin<=1'b0; //outputs for S1 state  
             green<=1'b1; //outputs for S1 state 
             if(!legal) carddam<=1'b1; //outputs for S1 state 
          end //end for outputs for S1 state 
          S2: begin //begin for outputs for S2 state 
             red <=1'b0; //outputs for S2 state 
             insuf<=1'b0; //outputs for S2 state 
             collect <=1'b0; //outputs for S2 state 
             alarm<=1'b0; //outputs for S2 state 
             askamt<=1'b0; //outputs for S2 state 
             green<=1'b1; //outputs for S2 state 
             carddam <=1'b0; //outputs for S2 state 
             askpin<=1'b1; //outputs for S2 state 
             if(!pin) wrongpin<=1'b1; //outputs for S2 state 
          end //end for outputs for S2 state 
          S3: begin //begin for outputs for S3 state 
             red <=1'b0; //outputs for S3 state 
             alarm<=1'b0; //outputs for S3 state 
             askamt<=1'b0; //outputs for S3 state 
             wrongpin<=1'b0; //outputs for S3 state 
             green<=1'b1; //outputs for S3 state 
             carddam <=1'b0; //outputs for S3 state 
             askpin<=1'b1; //outputs for S3 state 
             if(~amtok) insuf<=1'b1; //outputs for S3 state 
             else collect <=1'b1 ; //outputs for S3 state 
          end //end for outputs for S3 state 
          S4: begin //begin for outputs for S4 state 
             red <=1'b0; //outputs for S4 state 
             insuf<=1'b0; //outputs for S4 state 
             collect <=1'b0; //outputs for S4 state 
             askpin<=1'b0; //outputs for S4 state 
             wrongpin<=1'b0; //outputs for S4 state  
             green<=1'b1; //outputs for S4 state 
             carddam <=1'b0; //outputs for S4 state 
             if(repin) askamt<=1'b1; //outputs for S4 state 
             else alarm<=1'b1; //outputs for S4 state 
          end //end for outputs for S4 state 
        endcase //end of case 
     end //end of case 
endmodule //end of module 


module comparator(output reg less,equal,input [2:0] Data_in_A,Data_in_B); //module for
   //comparaing two inputs 
   always @ (Data_in_A , Data_in_B) //always for inputs 
     if(Data_in_A == Data_in_B) //if block for equality 
       begin //begin for if block 
          less <= 1'b0; //less value assigning 
          equal<= 1'b1; //equal value assigning 
       end //end of begin 
     else if(Data_in_A < Data_in_B) //if block for less 
       begin //begin for if block 
          less <= 1'b1; //less value assigning 
          equal<= 1'b0; //equal value assingning 
       end //end of begin of if 
     else //else for other things 
       begin //begin for else 
          less<=1'b0; //less value assigning 
          equal<=1'b0; //equal value assigning 
       end //end of else block 
endmodule //end of module 


// Test bench is 

module t_atm; //module for test bench  
   wire t_green,t_red,t_askpin,t_carddam,t_insuf,t_alarm,
        t_askamt,t_wrongpin,t_collect;
   //output variables
   
   reg  t_cash,t_legal, t_clock,t_reset; //input variables 
   reg [2:0] t_epin,t_amt,t_prepin,t_arepin,t_bal; //input variables 
   Mealy_atm M1              
     (t_green,t_red,t_askpin,t_carddam,t_insuf,t_alarm,
      t_askamt,t_wrongpin,t_collect ,t_cash,t_legal, 
      t_clock,t_reset,t_epin,t_amt,t_prepin,t_arepin,t_bal);
   //instantiation of Mealy_atm 
   initial #100 $finish; //termination time 
   initial //initial for clock signal 
     begin //begin of clock signal initial 
        t_clock=1'b0; //initial clock signal 
        forever #5 t_clock=~t_clock; //forever loop 
     end //end of initial block 
   initial //initial for assigning inputs 
     begin //begin for initial block 
        t_reset=1'b1; //input value of reset 
        #6 t_reset =1'b0;t_prepin=3'b000;t_bal=3'b111; //input values 
        #4 t_cash=1'b1; //input values 
        #5 t_legal=1'b1; //input values 
        #5 t_epin=3'b001; //input values 
        #5 t_amt=3'b001; //input values 
     end //end of initial block //input values 
endmodule //end of module //input values
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get unknown (X) on your output because you did not initialize one of your input signals: `t_arepin`.  It is declared as a `reg` type, which means its initial value is X.  When I set it to 0 in your testbench, all outputs become known.

```
   initial //initial for assigning inputs 
     begin //begin for initial block 
        t_reset=1'b1; //input value of reset 
        t_arepin = 0;
        #6 t_reset =1'b0;t_prepin=3'b000;t_bal=3'b111; //input values 
        #4 t_cash=1'b1; //input values 
        #5 t_legal=1'b1; //input values 
        #5 t_epin=3'b001; //input values 
        #5 t_amt=3'b001; //input values 
     end //end of initial block //input values
```